# Undefined variable in php while opening brwoser

Tags: php, image, variables, undefined, validating

**Undefined variable error is occurring while opening the php page in browser. Here example of image validation: No error in validating & Uploading the image., but i can't solve the Undefined variable error. plz help me.**

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
$rand=rand().time();
$photo_name=$_FILES['photo']['name'];
$photo_tmp_name=$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
$photo_name=explode(".",$photo_name);
list($width,$height) = getimagesize($photo_tmp_name);
if($photo_name[1]=="jpeg"||$photo_name[1]=="jpg"||$photo_name[1]=="gif")
{
    if($width<=365)
    {
        $photo_name=$photo_name[0].$rand.".".$photo_name[1];
        move_uploaded_file($photo_tmp_name,"Images/{$photo_name}");
    }
    else
    {   $sz_err="Not correct Perfect Size"; }
}
else
{   $tp_err="Not correct Type";         }   
}
```

//These two Bold Variables are "echo/print" in the body tag of the html. But Error occurring in the HTML LINE ONLY.

Comment: what is the error that gets displayed ? line number ?

Comment: What's the actual error message

Comment: simply add `@` to both variables `echo @$sz_err` and  `echo @$tp_err`.

Comment: @MarCejas that is not fixing the issue. That just hides it, which is not the proper way to code.

Comment: or `echo isset($var) ? $var : ''` but it would be better if you paste what lines occured the notice undefine variable and paste those lines.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

***Just Try With The Following :***

***PHP Part :***

```
<?php
$sz_err="";
$tp_err="";
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
$rand=rand().time();
$photo_name=$_FILES['photo']['name'];
$photo_tmp_name=$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
$photo_name=explode(".",$photo_name);
list($width,$height) = getimagesize($photo_tmp_name);
if($photo_name[1]=="jpeg"||$photo_name[1]=="jpg"||$photo_name[1]=="gif")
{
if($width<=365)
{
$photo_name=$photo_name[0].$rand.".".$photo_name[1];
move_uploaded_file($photo_tmp_name,"Images/{$photo_name}");
}
else
{ 
$sz_err="Not correct Perfect Size"; 
}
}
else
{ 
$tp_err="Not correct Type"; 
}
}
?>
```

I think this may help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: This is wrong, Those vars are being declared before any use and would not be the ones causing the error.

Comment: where they declared, did you seen any where in the given code ? and then which causing the error in the above code ?

Comment: Are you looking at the same code?!?! `$sz_err="Not correct Perfect Size";` and `$tp_err="Not correct Type";` See the `=` signs that means they are being declared and set to a value.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the PHP codings / logics, if you are assigning variable values inside the if(isset($_POST['save'])){ //codes } conditions means how could you access in HTML Part ? Is it possible ? <html><head><title>Image Upload</title></head><body><form><?php echo $sz_err;?><table><tr><td><input type="file" name="photo"></td></tr><tr><input type="submit" name="save"></td></tr></table></form></body></html>

Comment: Did you understand what i'm trying to explain to you and user ?

Comment: Are you asking is it possible to access those vars outside of the `if/else` statements? Is so, yes as they are in the global scope.

Comment: @cryptic In the above code(Sathya Velan) where they assigned in global ?